# Acquiring images from Zwo ASI camera in Mathematica Home Edition v 11.2.0.0

Tags: image-processing

I plan to use a ZWO ASI planetary camera (USB connection) for astronomical photography and would like to control the image acquisition using Mathematica. The issue is that although I have installed the ZWO camera on the laptop and the camera driver, and checked that the camera runs using different software (SharpCap), Mathematica does not recognize the camera as an imaging device. For example using

```
FindDevices[]
```

only returns the built-in webcam for the laptop. I also tried calling the name of the camera directly using

```
DeviceOpen["Camera","ZWO ASI120MM-S"]
```

but this also fails.

Is this even possible to accomplish, and if so, how?